# Render handler to be called when the user hits return key

Tags: react-native

I am creating a todo list. For the TextInput I do not want to use a button and the "onPress: () =>" handler to call my function with the users given text. Instead, I would like the user to just be able to hit the return key to call my function. It doesn't seem that react-native has an "onReturnKey" handler. Any suggestions for how I should go about this?

...

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { newTodo: '' };
  }

  AddNewTodo(text) {
    return console.log(text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText="VANO" />
        <Card>
          <CardSection style={{ backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7' }}>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>
              Reminders
            </Text>
          </CardSection>

          <CardSection>
            <Input
              placeholder="Create Reminder"
              returnKeyType='done'
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState(this.newTodo: text)}
              onSubmitEditing={() => this.AddNewTodo(this.state.newTodo)}
              value={this.state.newTodo}
            />
          </CardSection>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

The `TextInput` component has a prop for [returnKeyType](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype). You can use that in conjunction with [onSubmitEditing](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting) to run a function when the return key is pressed.

Example:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = { new_todo: '' }
}
render() {
    return (
        ....
        <TextInput
            returnKeyType={"done"}
            onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState(new_todo: text) }}
            onSubmitEditing={() => { myFunctionToAddNewTodo(this.state.new_todo) }}
            value={this.state.new_todo}/>
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: This still does not run my function when the return key is pressed. The returnKeyType prop seems to only determine how the key type will look.

Comment: @vanotech can you post a copy of the code you currently have as part of the question? It might be that you're missing something. Did you replace `myFunctionToAddNewTodo` with your custom function?

Comment: I have posted my code. When I enter text into my input and hit the return key, I receive nothing to my console log.